# como pasar un item por id de una pagina a otra con react

Tags: reactjs

```
const items = require("../../data/bots.json");

const Bots = () => {

    return (

        <section>
            <section class="working" className="grid">
                <div class="row">
                    {items.map((item) => (
                        <div class=".col-">
                            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className="card">
                                <Link 
                                    to={{ pathname: `/detail/${item.id}`, 
                                    state: { id: item.id }
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={`../../assets/bot/${item.Image}`} className="imgcard" />
                                </Link>
                                <h5>{item.Process}</h5>
                                <p>
                                    {item.Short}
                                </p>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Bots;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';
import Img from '../../assets/Background/hgs_digitalW.png'

let items = require("../../data/bots.json");

    let Detail = props => {
    
        return (
    
            <section>
                {items
                    .filter(item => item.id == props.match.params.id)
                    .map(item => (
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <h3>Business Function: <span>{item.Business}</span></h3>
                                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className="card">
    
                                    <Img src={`../../assets/bot/${item.Image}`} alt="" />
    
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
    
                    ))}
            </section>
        );
    }
    
export default Detail;
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de pasar de la pagina principal que tiene todos los items a otra para ver el detalle de ese item pero me sale error con el map

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Nicolas Esquivel/Desktop/DWC/src/components/Detail/index.js:19
  16 | 
  17 |    return (
  18 | 
> 19 |        <section>
     | ^  20 |            {items
  21 |                .filter(item => item.id == props.match.params.id)
  22 |                .map(item => (

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] y pasas el par de comentarios que acabas de hacer a la pregunta pues son pertinentes dentro de la misma.